# How to programmatically get current db schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to programmatically get current db schema as struct or enumerable or some like this. I'd like to walk through schema and know list of tables and fields with types and indexes and so on. Please provide api reference or class name and method or path to file from root of repo to see.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want some combination of `schema_search_path` and `tables`. See

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-schema_search_path

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-tables